# The first boot: Automate wizard and optimize

Tags: boot, system-installation, configuration, raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate

I have raspberry and Ubuntu Mate 20.04 (I could also use Ubuntu desktop for raspberry):

1. I am wondering if there is a way to automate "the first run wizard"? The first boot will prompt end-user-configuration dialog/service and would it be possible to create e.g. preseed file to automate system configuration?
2. Would it be possible to prevent partition resize? Or could I define an upper bound for resize?

In conclusion I would like to create an image, which would be ready to use when the power is switched to on.

Answer (score 0):

The standard method for pressed on ubuntu 20.10 is cloud-init its enabled by default and it can be used with the Ubuntu 20.10 Installer.     I use USB sticks for this purpose however cloud-init can be used to request the configuration data over the network.

Its very powerful and I frequently use to do unattended installs just boot it up and come back later to tell it to reboot the first time.

Perfect for the busy administrator I suggest you play with it in a virtual environment as its a quick learning curve.   Say with multipass or virtualbox.

https://ubuntu.com/blog/using-cloud-init-with-multipass

https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall

https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-quickstart

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/automated-server-installs/16612

https://gist.github.com/bitsandbooks/6e73ec61a44d9e17e1c21b3b8a0a9d4c